# Keyboard Navigation isn't working in Application Dashboard

Tags: keyboard, appmenu, navigation, dash-to-dock, gnome-dash

I am new to Ubuntu. If I click the *Show Applications* button then it shows me the workspaces.

I want to change it to directly show the applications dash. So, I installed a couple of extensions in order to do that:

1. [Start Overlay in Application View](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1198/start-overlay-in-application-view/)
2. [ESC to close overview from applications list | UPDATED](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3058/esc-to-close-overview-from-applications-list/)

Unfortunately, after installing these two extensions, my keyboard navigation buttons stopped working when entering to the applications dash. I've removed the extensions, but it's still the same. I can still access them using my mouse, but not with my keyboard navigation buttons.

[image: applications dash]

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension [Start Overlay in Application view](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1198/start-overlay-in-application-view/) does not appear to be updated anymore. Thus, it may not function correctly in your version of Gnome Shell.

A more up to date extension that does the same is [Show Applications instead of Workspaces](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1337/show-applications-instead-of-overview/). Try that: chances are that this will not exhibit the issue.

Another up to date extension that might suit you is [Activities icons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2872/activities-icons/). It changes the "Activities" button in two icons, one for the overview, and one for the application overview.

*Note*: This is a general drawback of Gnome Shell, the desktop environment used by Ubuntu, and its "Extensions" system. Extensions are maintained by individual developers, that have to accommodate for an ever changing Gnome Shell. Extensions that are not continuously maintained tend to break in newer Gnome Shell versions. Therefore, prefer to use extensions that are tested against your version of Gnome Shell, and preferably extensions that are well maintained. It is a good sign if, on the Gnome Extensions site, many versions of Gnome Shell are listed under the "Versions" drop down.

Comment: Thanks brother. It worked for me. I'm new in this OS . Hopefully I'll be helped by some of the helpful people like you.
Have a great day!